# GWT: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call

Tags: eclipse, gwt, persistence, rpc

Hi This is the exception i get when i run my GWT elicpse project. I'm using HSQLDB and Eclipselink.

```
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call        com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract void it.project.client.service.EmployeeService.createEmployee()' threw an unexpected exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No persistence providers available for "myDB" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:369)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectServerRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:352)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:115)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:480)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No persistence providers available for "myDB" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:180)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:70)
at it.ronf.server.ServiceImpl.AddettoServiceImpl.creaaddetti(AddettoServiceImpl.java:16)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
... 40 more
```

EDIT: i've correct the errornoticed in the comment in the bottom file.(problem still not solved!)

This is my **persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"  version="2.0">


    <persistence-unit name="myDB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class>it.project.shared.entity.Ecmployee</class>
    <class>it.project.shared.entity.Car</class>
    <class>it.project.shared.entity.Customer</class>


    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:${webroot}WEB-INF/db/inizData;shutdown=true;hsqldb.write_delay=false;"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="SA" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />

        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
    </properties>

  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

In my **build path** on eclipse, i have : eclipselink.jar ; gwt-servlet.jar ; hsqldb.jar ; javax.persistence_2.0.4.jar ; persistence-api-sources-2.0.jar ; smartgwt.jar

It's a week i search on internet but i can't find a solution..can you help to figure out what am i doing wrong? Feel free to ask for code or anything ..

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line: `<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>`

Have a look at http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html

Comment: it dind't change a lot, because if not specified it uses automatically a similar provider to execute the RPC...It gives me a very similar error now and i can't find solution for this either  @GWT4Ever

Comment: SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract void it.ronf.client.service.EmployeeService.createEmployee()' threw an unexpected exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Explicit persistence provider error(s) occurred for "myDB" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl from provider: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl

Comment: try adding the "api" part between the provider tags: from org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider to org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl

Comment: nope using this provider :<provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
the error is the same :(

Comment: 2 other notices: 1) there is no closing persistence tag, 2) you use version 1.0 in the XML and 2.0 for your libraries. So try this persistence opening tag instead: <persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

Comment: 1)yes, my bad, i forget to copy from the file but it was there.
2)thanks for the notice , now i've correct it, but still there's no differences in the error.
this jpa is killing all my patiance